# WPF/Silverlight: Attached Properties and Garbage Collection

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, attached-properties

Lets say I've got a textbox and an attached property called Foo.Bar.

```
<Textbox local:Foo.Bar="5" />
```

Does the attached property hold a strong reference to the textbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they should not, you can think of DependencyObejcts as dictionaries and of Dependency / Attached properties as keys in the dictionary.

The OnBarChanged can do whatever it wants with the TextBox though, it could potentially keep a strong reference to it somewhere.